# Bad performance ASP.NET MVC ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I need advice about my application.

First of all, I have two models which represent two tables (there are not the real tables)

CUSTOMERS (135K rows | 40 columns)

```
+-------------+--------+------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID |  NAME  | FIRST_NAME |
+-------------+--------+------------+
|        1234 | DUPONT | JEAN       |
+-------------+--------+------------+
```

ORDERS

```
+-------------+----------+-------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | ORDER_ID | TYPE  |
+-------------+----------+-------+
|        1234 |     5678 | MEET  |
|        1234 |     9105 | CANDY |
|        2568 |     7523 | CANDY |
+-------------+----------+-------+
```

I want to get a customer with his list of orders.

So I created a Viewmodel :

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string Name  { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public List<OrdersViewModel> Orders { get; set; }

    public ViewModel(){Orders = new List<OrdersViewModel>(); 
}
```

And now the query  :

```
var query = from c in northwind.CUSTOMERS
            select new ViewModel()
                       {
                           CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                           Name = c.Name,
                           FirstName = c.FirstName
                       };
var CustomersModels = query.ToList();
var queryOrders = from c in northwind.CUSTOMERS
                  join o in northwind.ORDERS
                  on c.CustomerID  equals o.CustomerID 
                  select new OrdersViewModel()
                             { 
                                 CustomerID = d.CustomerID,
                                 OrderId= d.OrderId,
                                 Type= d.Type
                             };
var modelsOrders = queryOrders .ToList();

foreach (ViewModel item in modelsOrders )
{
    var listModels = modelsOrders .Where(e => e.PMRQTOTM ==  item.PMRQTOTM).ToList();
    item.Orders = listModels;
}
```

Is there a better way to realise this?

I get the `CustomerModel` in less than 30 seconds but for the order it takes several minutes...

Comment: That's crazy slow!!! Do you have an index on the CustomerID fields of your tables?

Comment: Your code isn't making any sense, where is `doc` defined?

Comment: How many orders are you pulling up per customer?

Comment: And where is modelsDoc defined? Seems like you're doing a lot of iterating.

Comment: Are you trying to show all orders for all customers? Or the orders for a certain customer?

Comment: @RobertMoskal is right, you're joining on two columns that are likely `NVARCHAR(MAX)` (the default DB type for a string property with EF) based on your code here. That's crazy inefficient. If you need a string ID, you need to set a max length on it (`[MaxLength(50)]`) and create an index (`[Index]`).

Comment: you say you want A customer but you're not using `where CustomerID == 123` in you customer query

Comment: @RobertMoskal no i haven't index..

Comment: @Dai just a bad copy/past sorry

Comment: @JB06  i'm trying to all customers with their orders

Comment: I you create indexes your query will happen instantly :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Customer and Order has a relationship, you can use [Include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708(v=vs.110).aspx) in first query.

Even then you should not query 135K all at once. Instead, you want to use **Skip** and **Take** based on **Page Size** and **Page Index**.

Comment: It's for reporting ( excel) so i need all records

Comment: @AnTho Do not retrieve all records. Web server will run out of memory, and eventually throw ***System.OutOfMemory exception***. Instead, you want to retrieve few records at a time and append to the existing excel file.

Comment: Ok i understand, is it possible to have a sample ? but it will be realy faster ?

Comment: @AnTho Sorry, I do not have a sample, but you can search in SO. `but it will be realy faster?` Answer is no, but it guarantees that server won't throw exception.

Comment: i fixed the problem thank you ! i generate the excel in 1min40 is it to slow ? the workbook was created in 30 second but the saveAs() memory stream take 1 min... i use EPPLUS

Answer (score 0):

Oy, just create the appropriate indexes on your tables and your queries will fly:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX CUSTOMERS_CUSTOMER_ID
ON CUSTOMERS (CUSTOMER_ID)

CREATE INDEX ORDERS_CUSTOMER_ID
ON ORDERS (CUSTOMER_ID)
```